# java.lang.outofmemory error (web services) on android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I am using simple web services to access the data from the database which is on the server. I am using android api10 but when running the code I get an error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

My code is:

```
package com.android.webservicesdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class androidactivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/getAllDealsbyCategorySer";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "getAllDealsbyCategorySer";
    private static String URL = "http://dosha.dotnetgeekz.com/ServerServices.asmx?WSDL";
    static final String KEY_DEAL = "deals"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_HEADLINE = "DealHeadline";
    static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "DealCategory";
    static final String KEY_PRICE = "BuyPrice";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Button btnFar, btnCel, btnClear;
    EditText txtFar, txtCel;
    TextView textView2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mains);

        btnFar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFar);
        txtFar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFar);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Initialize soap request + add parameters
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
                // Use this to add parameters
                request.addProperty("category", txtFar.getText().toString());
                // Declare the version of the SOAP request
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                try {
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
                    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        // Get the first property and change the label text                 
                        textView2.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
08-31 11:36:06.606: E/dalvikvm-heap(334): Out of memory on a 2813318-byte allocation.
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:153)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject.toString(SoapObject.java:646)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.webservicesdemo.androidactivity$1.onClick(androidactivity.java:84)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How much data You're trying to obtain by the request? From log it looks a lot of. Have You tried to split request into 2-3 separate sequence requests?

Comment: How you try this call in android `AsyncTask` or Thread .

Comment: its just because of large numbers of records, try to send request to get the some fixed number of records in a single request, used start and end index of record.

Comment: What is the category you pass into request?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that your SOAP response is too big?

```
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject.toString(SoapObject.java:646)
08-31 11:36:06.660: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.webservicesdemo.androidactivity$1.onClick(androidactivity.java:84)
```

Probably caused by line below

```
textView2.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
```

Top line also mentiones that String's length is possibly 2813318.

```
08-31 11:36:06.606: E/dalvikvm-heap(334): Out of memory on a 2813318-byte allocation.
```

Comment: With this much of a question, I think best answer is to point the problem.